# Automatic login to dropbox account by logging into wordpress admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress, dropbox

a client is asking to be able to logging in to his dropbox account (so he can browse files and folders in dropbox) whenever He authenticates to his wordpress blog.

there's any way to achieve that?
Thanks

Luca

Answer (score 0):

Yep there are quite a few plugins for dropbox integration with wordpress.
http://wpmu.org/9-dropbox-plugins-for-wordpress/

I think that this is exactly what you are looking for http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pressbox/

Hope it's useful.

Comment: when I install it  I receive a wordpress error : The plugin does not have a valid header.